# ¿Cómo hacer dinámico el select option en base a un monto para calcular unas cuotas?

Tags: php, javascript, select

El problema que tengo es que no logro hacer dinámico el **select option**, cuando lo intento no me está obteniendo los datos del **array** para luego usarlos si coloco **20000** me debe mostrar solo el **opt_1** pero no lo está haciendo.

Comparto mi código a continuación:

```js
            //1) Defino Las Variables Correspondintes
            var opt_1 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses");
            var opt_3 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses");
            var opt_3 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses","18 meses", "24 meses");
            var opt_4 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses","18 meses", "24 meses","36 meses", "48 meses");
            // 2) crear una funcion que permita ejecutar el cambio dinamico
            $("#valores").change(function cambia() {
                var valor =  $("#valores").val();
                //se chequea si esta definida
                if(valor<=30000){
                    //selecionamos
                    mis_opts=eval("opt_1");
                    //se calcula el numero de valor
                    num_opts=mis_opts.length;
                    //marco el numero de opt en el select
                    document.formulario1.opt.length = num_opts;
                    //para cada opt del array, la pongo en el select
                    for(i=0; i<num_opts; i++){
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[i].value=mis_opts[i];
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[i].text=mis_opts[i];
                    }
                    }else{
                        //si no habia ningun valor
                        document.formulario1.opt.length = 1;
                        //ponemos un guion en la unica opt que he dejado
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[0].value="-";
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[0].text="-";
                    }
                    //hacer un reset de las opts
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[0].selected = true;
                    
                }
            )
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
    <head>
        <title>Select Dinamico</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        .seleccion{
            border: 3px solid #58ACFA;
            background-color:#2ECCFA;
            color:white;
            font-size:17px;
            width:150px;
            height:35px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="formulario1" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="valors" id="valores" readonly="cambia()" value="20000">
        
            <select class="seleccion" name="opt">
                <option value="-">-
            </select>
            
        </form>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //1) Defino Las Variables Correspondintes
            var opt_1 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses");
            var opt_3 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses");
            var opt_3 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses","18 meses", "24 meses");
            var opt_4 = new Array ("-", "3 meses", "6 meses","9 meses", "12 meses","18 meses", "24 meses","36 meses", "48 meses");
            // 2) crear una funcion que permita ejecutar el cambio dinamico
            $("#valores").change(function cambia() {
                var valor =  $("#valores").val();
                //se chequea si esta definida
                if(valor<=30000){
                    //selecionamos
                    mis_opts=eval("opt_1");
                    //se calcula el numero de valor
                    num_opts=mis_opts.length;
                    //marco el numero de opt en el select
                    document.formulario1.opt.length = num_opts;
                    //para cada opt del array, la pongo en el select
                    for(i=0; i<num_opts; i++){
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[i].value=mis_opts[i];
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[i].text=mis_opts[i];
                    }
                    }else{
                        //si no habia ningun valor
                        document.formulario1.opt.length = 1;
                        //ponemos un guion en la unica opt que he dejado
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[0].value="-";
                        document.formulario1.opt.options[0].text="-";
                    }
                    //hacer un reset de las opts
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[0].selected = true;
                    
                }
            )
            
        
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: La variable mis_opts ha sido declarada?

Comment: Además, te falta cerrar la etiqueta <option></option>

Answer (score -1):

en la parte:

```
$("#valores").change(function cambia() {
```

substituye `cambia` por un espacio en blanco

PD: deja los paréntesis.

---

El fundamento de esto, es que los eventos llamados de esta forma en JQuery tienen que llamar funciones anonimas.

referencia: https://api.jquery.com/change/